# get value of listbox in php

Tags: php, listbox

I have the following code:

```
<td>Province</td>
<td>
<select name="prov">
<?php 
$sql1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM Provincetbl order by Prov_Desc desc");
while ($row1 = $sql1->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<option value="prov1"><?php echo $row1['Prov_Desc']; ?> </option>
<?php 
}
?>
</select><br><br></td></tr>
<td>Distrect</td>
<td>
<select name="dist">
<?php 
$sql2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM Distrecttbl order by Distrect_Desc desc");
while ($row2 = $sql2->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<option value="dist1"><?php echo $row2['Distrect_Desc']; ?> </option>
<?php 
}
?></select></td></tr>
```

There are two listboxes prov and dist. I have been trying to figure out how to read the value of either listbox (i.e get it in a variable). I have found a post which states that the value of a listbox is read after the form is posted (in the variable $_Post). However, I am dealing with a listbox which is not sending anything to the server, so why is the value of the listbox read after the form is posted?
Second, I do not have a form element in my page to begin with..?
Other posts have stated that I can read the value of listbox in a variable $prov or $dist. However I cannot seem to echo the contents of these variables to the screen.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is it not showing your dropdown values now?

Comment: The prov and dist listboxes are displaying the values correctly. What I need is to get the selected value in a variable so I can use it in a query. How can I get the selected value of the prov and dist listboxes? Does this have to do with form submission?

Comment: Have you tried AJAX?

Comment: I am getting acquainted with AJAX concepts... I was able to get the value of the listbox using javascript. It is now a question of passing this value to php and constructing a query based on that value. I would welcome any hints... I am seeking to display a table based on php query using the value of the listbox. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think all the options in the prov listbox will have the same value that you've wrote 'prov1' and the second listbox will have dist1 in all the options  
What I recommande you to do is the following : 
`<option value="$row1['Prov_Desc']"><?php echo $row1['Prov_Desc']; ?> </option>` 
and for the second one use this :
`<option value="$row2['Distrect_Desc']"><?php echo $row2['Distrect_Desc']; ?> </option>`

Comment: I agree about the value of the listbox, but the code should be: <option value="<?php echo $row1['Prov_ID']; ?>";>

Comment: Well I couldn't figure that there is an index called 'Prov_ID' so I gived the answer based on what I've read on the question.